# Given marginal tables back solve for contingency table

Tags: python, back-transformation, simultaneous-equation

How to programmatically solve problems similar to the below:

Most basic example: Given two marginal tables, solve for 2x2 distribution.

| A | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 7 |

| B | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 6 |

Solve for

| A | B | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |  |
| 0 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 1 |  |

The solution needs to be scalable. For example, given `n * m` and `n * z` solve for `n * m * z`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't exactly follow your question. However, there is more information
in the bivariate distribution than can be retrieved from the two marginal
distributions. That holds for sample distributions as well.

Consider:

```
TABLE 1    A  not A   TOTAL

B         25   25       50
not B     25   25       50

TOTAL     50   50      100
```

and

```
TABLE 2    A  not A   TOTAL

B         50    0       50
not B      0   50       50

TOTAL     50   50      100
```

Moreover, there are many other $2\times 2$ tables
that have the same marginals.

If you believe that (or want to test whether) the A categories (columns) and the
B categories (rows) are *independent,* Table 1 is what you want.
That would would be the table of
*expected counts* for a chi-squared test.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.